# how to hide thumbnail pane using powerpoint add-in

Tags: c#, add-in, powerpoint

i would like to ask a quick question:
how can i hide thumbnail pane in the left side?

see image:
http://goo.gl/YjXk5

i have read this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bf08984t.aspx

it seems impossible but i would like to know if there's other way...

also i'm developing PowerPoint 2013 not 2010 or 2007
and i noticed that in PPT 2013 in thumbnail pane it doesn't have "X" close button unlike previous versions...

Answer (score 0):

```
ActiveWindow.ViewType = ppViewSlide
```

If you're automating from another app, ppViewSlide is a PPT application constant, VBA Long = 1